# Is there any species of corydoras catfishes that can live at pond temperatures?

Tags: fish, pond, temperature

My pond reaches temperatures as low as 20 F, rarely that low though. It does ice over from time to time in the winter.

Is there any variety of corydoras catfish that can live there? I found some pond shops sell catfish for use in ponds, such as blue catfish, but these reach massive sizes, I don't want something that will threaten baby fish.

Comment: Why ? Koi are good scavengers and  are vegetarians , and tolerate freezing temperatures. Danios ( and formerly swordtails , mollies,etc ) breed in my pond and are not bothered by large koi.

Comment: Because they look nice.

Comment: You can't see them in a pond unless it is a small bare plastic tub.

Comment: @blacksmith37 What if I have a school of 300 of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catfish will grow big but also can't take that low temp that I know. Regarding Corys, same thing there is not one that can hold that low temp.